# JS fiddle with crunchbase API not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

For some reason, the js fiddle with crunchbase api is not working. Been searching the web for possible solution since morning

I already tried to change the jquery that was there in different parts. Also, trying to change the tags around. Here is JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/myh2002/f8Pn4/12/

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="searchcontainer"> 
    <div id="search">
        <input placeholder="enter name"></input>
        <div id="source">Powered by Crunchbase</div>
    </div>
    </div>
<div id="form">     
    <div id="desc"></div>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <div id="total"></div>
    <div id="acquired"></div>
    <div id="comp"></div>
</div>
```

Actual result is when i tried to enter a search result, its broken. Expected result is for the search term to show up

Comment: "jquery-2.0.2.js:7667 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://static.crunchbase.com/api/api_deprecation.html with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details."

Comment: You should remove your api key from the fiddle, and also revoke it and generate a new one.